# defer и only в django, исключить поле из объекта

Tags: django, orm

Доброго времени суток, господа. *django 1.9.* Помогите с одним вопросом: **знаю о наличии defer и only** но тем не менее, исключаемые поля все так же потенциально доступны в шаблоне. Ниже приведу пример...

**views.py**

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object(queryset=Questions.objects.select_related("extuser__username").defer("extuser__password"))
    return super(QuestionPage, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**template.html**

```
{{ question.extuser.password }}
```

В итоге это самое поле `password` в модели `ExtUser` все так же доступно для вывода, а я хочу чтобы даже из шаблона нельзя было его получить. Неужели использовать `values/values_list` - это единственное решение? Спасибо.

Comment: `defer()` - это механизм отложенной загрузки полей, содержащих большие объёмы данных. Приведённый вами код обращается в базу дважды - один раз за всеми полями, кроме `password`, а потом ещё один раз, когда вы обращаетесь к `password` из шаблона. Так что, если вы пытались как-то оптимизировать обращения к базе, то вы только ухудшили ситуацию.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, черт с этой оптимизацией, изначально вопрос стоит в том чтобы **НИКАКИМ** образом: ни с шаблона, ни в коде нельзя было получить доступ к ненужном полю (в данном случае password). К ненужному полю априори обращения и не будет. Просто я беспокоюсь за безопасность. Мало ли, в будущем, горе-верстальщик неумышленно (а мб и наоборот) выведет этот самый **password автора** на главной странице, или др. личную инфу. Есть ли выход? Или остается только, вариант набирать проверенных верстальщиков?) Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы запретить доступ к атрибуту объекта из шаблона, измените его имя так чтобы оно начиналось с символа нижнего подчёркивания - `_password`. Название поля в таблице можно оставить без изменений, явно задав его параметром [db_column](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#db-column).

Comment: а это точно полностью защитит от нежелательного/неосторожного доступа к полю? И если же мне понадобится поле в коде, а в шаблоне нет?

Comment: Шаблонизатор выдаст ошибку при попытке обращения к `_password`. В коде к этому атрибуту обращаться можно свободно.

Comment: У меня имеется своя модель **ExtUser** заместо **User**, в ней прописаны _username_ и тд. **ExtUser** наследует **AbstractBaseUser и PermissionsMixin**, в AbstractUser'e содержится как раз password, менять исходники - плохо. Вытекает вопрос: можно прям в **ExtUser** переопределить password и дописать db_colum?

Answer (score 0):

Я, боясь за написанное выше, реализовал вот такое шайтан-устройство.

```
def delete_attr(self, obj, *args):
    """
    Function accept `obj`, in which will be deleted all 
    fields that names there are in `args`

    For every new object, subobject - new call [bug :( ]
    """
    if not args:
        args = self.disallowed_fields
    for field in args:
        delattr(obj, field)
    return obj
```

Имеет ли оно место на существование? Думаю, оно ясно как божий день.

Comment: monkey patching - это путь к приключениям, его стоит использовать только тогда, когда других возможностей нет.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev но ведь функция совсем маленькая, описание -
почти как она сама, говорящее название. + класс (эта функция обернута в класс) подключается как модуль во view